# Longest file path in a folder - how to handle exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

This function should find the longest file in a path it get as parameter.
It seems to work well the problem is I’m not sure how to handle exceptions.
In case of PathTooLongException I want to set _MaxPath to -2 and exit the function, in case of other exception set it to -1 and exit the function else set it to longest file path.
I'm not sure what is the right way to handle exceptions in that case.

Probably a dumb question but I’m new with C#...

```
static int _MaxPath = 0;
public static void GetLongestFilePath(string p)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(p))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                if (f.Length > _MaxPath)
                {
                    _MaxPath = f.Length;
                }
            }
            GetLongestFilePath(d);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is PathTooLongException)
        {
            _MaxPath = -1;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(-99);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you store result in static field? Thats not convenient. Also a method with a name that starts with `Get` is supposed to return something, it should not be void.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple catch blocks with multiple Exception types:

```
    try
    {
       // ...
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException e)
    {
       _MaxPath = -2;
       return;
    }
    catch (Exception e) //anything else
    {
       _MaxPath = -1;
       // ...
    }
    finally 
    {
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, But how should I exit the function in case of exception ? 
if I use System.Environment.Exit(-99) in the finally and debug it, it doesn't enter the catch statements.

Comment: If you use the return statement in the `catch` block, it will exit the method immediately.  You do not need it.  Remove the return statement and it will run the `finally` block.

Comment: I don’t understand why but when I have a Finally block it doesn’t enter the catch block also if I use return it doesn’t totally exit the function maybe since it's recursive.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the specific exception type in its own block:

```
static int _MaxPath = 0;
public static void GetLongestFilePath(string p)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(p))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                if (f.Length > _MaxPath)
                {
                    _MaxPath = f.Length;
                }
            }
            GetLongestFilePath(d);
        }
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException e)
    {
        _MaxPath = -2;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _MaxPath = -1;
    }
    finally
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(-99);
    }
}
```